# Eric Flint's "Mother of Demons" Enagulishuc language rules?

Tags: novel, aliens, languages, space-colonization

I've been trying to figure out the rules for Enagulishuc, the English dialect spoken by Gukuy (and demons) in Eric Flint's  1997 first novel "Mother of Demons". The Gukuy are alien mollusks with siphons for mouths who develop their own accent/dialect of English. I also posted this question on the Baen forum to try for a direct response from the author, but have not yet received a response from the author. Google recognizes the word "Enagulishuc" as being the word "English", so no help there.

What I'm looking for is a note or interview quote or something from the author himself, in which he describes at least some of the specifics of the process by which he transliterated English words into their Enagulishuc equivalent. I'm hoping for a detailed enough description to be able to transliterate anything and everything.

I wrote out the Enagulishuc words and their English equivalents to figure out what I could on my own - so far what I've got is that aspirates are difficult for Gukuy to pronounce, so H becomes silent and an initial P sometimes has an A placed before it. CH (and usually J) becomes DZH (assuming similar to Mandarin pinyin Z?). Initial J can become Y, if the original form of the name used a Y (Yosef). S becomes SH. Consonants usually separated with vowels similar to English loan-words in Japan. Final consonant often adds a U, sometimes I, sometimes none. Some sounds unchanged, such as F.

Enagulishuc names transliterated from English in the novel:

Indira Toledo - Inudiratoledo

Joseph Adekunle - Yoshefadekunula

Jens Knudsen - Dzhenushkunutushen

Ludmilla Rozkowski - Ludumilaroshokavashiki

Takashi Mizoguchi - Takashimitodzhugudzhi

Maria De Los Reyes - Mariyaduloshruyush

Andrew MacPherson - Anadurumakfurrushen

(Angus O'Hara?) - Anagushohara

(Baron Friedrich von) Steuben - shutuppen (one who teaches the craft of war)

Stalingrad - Shatalunungurdu

Enagulishuc words used in the novel:

boys - buyush

captain - kapitanu

child - dzhiludh

children - dzhiludhurren

English - Enagulishuc

girl - gurrul

human - ummun

hundred - unnunduredh

lieutenant - liyutenanatu (note: based on American pronunciation)

nation - nashiyonu

phalanx - falanuksh

platoons - apalatunush

prickly - purrikkulai

sergeant major - sharredzhenutumadzhoru